# How to change variable value for java.lang.Integer in eclipse debugging?

Tags: java, eclipse

private Integer ownerId;

here Integer is non-primitive type, In debugging can anyone tell how to change value for this above mentioned variable?

Answer (score 2):

In Eclipse there is a debug window on the right up side which has a variable window in it. That window shows all the relevant variables to the code you have the breakpoint on. you can change the variables values there.[image]